# Problema con sympy e input

Tags: python, input, sympy, diff

Estoy intentando hacer un programa simple que le pregunte al usuario una función para que sea derivada con el paquete de simpy, pero al usar `y=input()` y después intentar derivar eso con `y.diff(x)` me da el siguiente error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'diff'`

Este es el código que he intentado:

```
from scipy.misc import derivative
from sympy import *
from sympy import sympify

#Derivada
def derivar():
    x=Symbol('x')
    print("Usaremos x como variable, si tu función tiene otra, sustitúyela por x \n Ejemplo: 2*t**3 sería 2*x**3") 
    y=(input("Dame tu función (Recuerda usar bien los paréntesis y que los exponentes se escriben con ** \n Ejemplo: 2*x**3 se lee: Dos equis al cubo): "))
    derivada=(y.diff(x))
    print("La derivada de ", y, "es \n", derivada)
    print("¿Quieres evaluar la función en algún valor? \n 1:Sí \n 2:No")
derivar()
```

Comment: Hola Francisco! Es recomendado que se adjunte el código en formato texto, así nos lo pones más fácil a las personas que te queremos ayudar, ya que en vez de tener que escribir todo el código, simplemente tenemos que copiar y pegar.

Comment: from sympy import Symbol
from scipy.misc import derivative
from sympy import *
from sympy import sympify

#Derivada
def derivar():
    x=Symbol('x')
    print("Usaremos x como variable, si tu función tiene otra, sustitúyela por x \n Ejemplo: 2*t**3 sería 2*x**3") 
    y=(input("Dame tu función (Recuerda usar bien los paréntesis y que los exponentes se escriben con ** \n Ejemplo: 2*x**3 se lee: Dos equis al cubo): "))
    derivada=sympify(y.diff(x))
    print("La derivada de ", y, "es \n", derivada)

Comment: una disculpae s que soy nuevo en esto jajaj

Comment: No te preocupes nadie nace sabiendo, yo cuando llegue en su día no tenía ni idea de que era esto, y hoy día tampoco sé muchas cosas. Te recomiendo hacer [El Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) de una forma rápida y sencilla te enterarás de como funciona la comunidad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error lo que te dice, es que un **string** que es el tipo de dato que le estás pasando, no tiene el atributo `diff`.

Lo que tienes que hacer es transformar el input que recives como string a una expresión, con sympy es fácil, solo tienes que usar `parse_expr()` para parsear tu string a tipo expresión.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
from scipy.misc import derivative
from sympy import *
from sympy import sympify
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

#Derivada
def derivar():
    x=Symbol('x')
    print("Usaremos x como variable, si tu función tiene otra, sustitúyela por x \n Ejemplo: 2*t**3 sería 2*x**3") 

    #Parseamos de string a expresión
    y=parse_expr(input("Dame tu función (Recuerda usar bien los paréntesis y que los exponentes se escriben con ** \n Ejemplo: 2*x**3 se lee: Dos equis al cubo): "))

    derivada=(y.diff(x))
    print("La derivada de ", y, "es \n", derivada)
    print("¿Quieres evaluar la función en algún valor? \n 1:Sí \n 2:No")
derivar()
```

Comment: Gracias amigo! Soy nuevo en esto y estuve buscando mucho alguna función como esa pero no encontraba en ningún lado, te agareadezco mucho.

Comment: Me alegro de ser de ayuda!! Aunque como eres nuevo probablemente no lo sepas, la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow en marcando la respuesta como "respuesta correcta" y por qué no, dar un voto positivo (cuando tengas reputación)